# How to get array to print correctly with constructor and class? Java

Tags: java, arrays, printing, constructor

I'm simply trying to get my array to print correctly. This is what I have so far.

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //create new instance of the ArrayLab class with parameter of 10
        ArrayClass array = new ArrayLab(10);

        array.initialize();
}
```

---

I do realize that I have a parameter for my class, the problem remains the same whether or not I have just a simple instance variable with the class parameter inside of the java array field.

---

```
public class ArrayClass
{
    //array instance variable
    private int[] array = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    //array constructor
    public ArrayClass(int integer)
    {
        //array parameter field [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 10 in total.
        int[] temp = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        array = temp;

    }

    public void initialize()
    {

        System.out.println(array);

    }
}
```

It all compiles, but the problem I'm having is when it prints the output is comes up as something like this [I@1443957. What does that imply?

Comment: The constructor for `ArrayClass` must be names `ArrayClass` not `ArrayLab`...

Comment: fixed, still same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to print it in next way:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: cannot find symbol - variable Arrays.

Comment: @pewpew Your should import Arrays class:

'import java.util.Arrays;'

at the beginning of your class definition

Comment: It worked! Thanks :)

Comment: @pewpew accept answer will be more that enough. :)

Comment: How is this not in the oracle docs? Or am I blind?

Comment: @pewpew it is there. It's native java lib
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: ok I see it, its at the very bottom. LOL, ok I was using a different documentation that this one. i was using this. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html